# find element by id and append link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I'm using jquery to fetch and loop over data. On each iteration it has to append a link to a list item. I'm hitting a wall with the conditional check. I need to check whether a list item already has a link and if so just append to the data-content attribute and not overwrite the entire link, which is currently happening.

The way the code is now it never hits the else, which doesn't make sense. I need fresh eyes to point out the obvious.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'training/calendar',
    datatype: 'json'
})
.done(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        var date = new Date(v.date);
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var strMonth = textMonth(month);

        if ($('.calendar').find("li[id='" + strMonth.toLowerCase() + day + "']").find('a')) {
            var $this = $("li[id='" + strMonth.toLowerCase() + day + "']").find('a');
            $($this).data('content', $($this).data('content') + "--------------" + v.name + ' ' + v.address);
        } else {
            $('.calendar').find("li[id='" + strMonth.toLowerCase() + day + "']").text('').addClass('event').css({
                'border-radius': '24px',
                'background-color': v.colour
            })
            .append("<a href='#' tabindex='0' role='button' " +
            "data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='focus' data-placement='top' " +
            "data-content='" + v.name + ', ' + v.address + "' class='details'>" + day + "</a>");
        }
        $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();
        $('a.details').on('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); return true;});
    });
});
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair The edit was hardly an improvement on the question though.

Comment: @DarkAshelin ...and? :) Did you follow the meta-discussion on this issue?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I think the [2nd highest answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179969) on that meta discussion applies more for this question. In my opinion it made the title less vague. But this isn't really worth a lengthy discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `$('.calendar').find("li[id='" + strMonth.toLowerCase() + day + "']").find('a')` will never output `false`. It will give a jQuery object even if it finds nothing.

Change your `if` statement as following and you should get better results:

```
var a = $('.calendar').find("li[id='" + strMonth.toLowerCase() + day + "']").find('a');

if ( a.get(0) != undefined ) {
    // .get(0) will retrieve the DOM element from a jQuery object. 
    // If the DOM element doesn't exist, it will return undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get any object than it have some length.so you can able to use length property.

```
var xyz = $('.calendar').find("li[id='" + strMonth.toLowerCase() + day + "']").find('a');

if(xyz.length){


  //'a' is available there  
} else {

 //'a' is not available
}
```